# Is it possbile to change the webpages_Membership, roles etc table names from a simple template created with web matrix?

Tags: webmatrix

I've created a Web Matrix web site from the starter template which creates a database with the a few tables for the login details. Most of these are names webpages_Membership, webpages_Roles etc. The hosting company I use only gives me one database and I want to have more than one site on the server. I want to prefix the table name with something to make it unique, but it looks like the web matrix framework will only work with the set table name. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use SQL Server Compact Edition, you can have as many databases as you like in your App_Data folder. Certainly something to consider if your sites aren't likely to be hugely busy. Otherwise you can develop your own Provider inheriting from `ExtendedMembershipProvider`  and make it "site-aware". Dig around in the [WebMatrix.Data](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781) source code for more details (available as part of the MVC source download).